# I'm having a global name error with python

Tags: python

So, I'm starting python python and I encountered with this error.

```
 def CheckMail(mail):
      if re.match("[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+" , mail):
           correo = mail 
      else:
           print "Ingrese el formato correcto para el correo: "
           mail = raw_input()
           CheckMail(mail)
```

when I call the function and its true no problem, but when I call the function and goes to the else, gives me

```
NameError: global name 'CheckMail' is not defined
```

I am certain the error is when I call the recursion, what I do not know is what is causing the error.

Thanks!

Edit: added actual code

Comment: Please give the minimal  version of the  code which produces this error, your current code will simply not run..

Comment: Are you 100% sure stuff2 is of the same type as stuff? Please show the relevant code, this is too abstract

Comment: Use a different variable name for your new prompt.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I forgot the colons in this example, Im having a little trouble posting the  code, Im sorta new here :S

Comment: yes, it says line 11, witch matches with my code line.

Comment: ok, for some reason, if I create my function before I call it I get an error right where I told you, I created it after I call it I get the same error but on the line where I call it

Comment: I am able to run this program with no errors.

import re
def CheckMail(mail):
      if re.match("[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+" , mail):
           correo = mail 
      else:
           print "Ingrese el formato correcto para el correo: "
           mail = raw_input()
           CheckMail(mail)
                
CheckMail("Hello")

Comment: wait. Import? I have a class, inside this class  I have this function. I call the function I get the error. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Your function is inside a class:

```
class myclass(object):
    def CheckMail(mail):
          if re.match("[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+" , mail):
               correo = mail 
          else:
               print "Ingrese el formato correcto para el correo: "
               mail = raw_input()
               CheckMail(mail)
```

I can't tell what your application is (and don't know what the rest of the class looks like).  It looks like this needs to be a method, and `correo` is part of the object state.  If that is the case:

Your method's def should be:

```
def CheckMail(self, mail):
```

When you call `obj.CheckMail(m)`, it passes a reference to 'self', so that the class knows which object it is working on.

Your definition should (probably) be:

```
self.correo = mail
```

I'm assuming that you're storing `correo` in the object for some purpose.

And to call a class method from within the class, it should be:

```
self.CheckMail(mail)
```

This will call CheckMail and pass the same object into the function.  The error is raised because CheckMail does not exist as a global name.  There is however a myclass.CheckMail function.  To call that function, you need to use self (or another obj of myclass).

If this is indeed the problem you're having, I would highly recommend checking out https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html.  It is a very good brief overview of how class syntax works in python.